# SQL query help needed to include non matching records

Tags: sql

I have got a requirement to display a query which shows matching and non matching rows against the master lookup table

The `@PostCodes` table contains the postcodes for master table which the second query would be matched against

```
DECLARE @PostCodes TABLE 
(
    RowID int not null primary key identity(1,1), 
    Postcodes varchar(100) 
) 


SELECT 
   C.CampaignId, C.Name, C.Description,C.EndedOn, C.Active, C.Manager, 
   P.PostcodeArea, P.PostcodeDistrict
FROM 
   Campaign C, CampaignPostcode P, @PostCodes pc
WHERE 
   P.CampaignId = C.CampaignId AND
   P.PostcodeDistrict = pc.Postcodes AND
   C.EndedOn IS NULL
```

The second query returns me only the matching records against postcodes and I have tried everything to include unmatched records but no luck.

Any help?

---

### EDIT (Tables)

```
 PostCodes  (table1)             Campaign (table2)                      

Id      Postcodes          CampaignId    Name      Desc           
1        AA                  1            camp1    Desc1
2        AB                  2            camp2    Desc2 
3        AC                  3            camp3    Desc3
4        AD                  4            camp4    Desc4

CampaignPostcode (table3)

CampaignPostcodeId  CampaignId  PostcodeArea
 1                      1          AA
 2                      2          AB
 3                      2          AB
 4                      3          AC
```

Output Required

```
   Id  CampaignName   Desc   PostcodeIn PostcodeOut
    1    Camp1        Desc1     AA          NULL
    2    Camp2        Desc2     AB          NULL
    3    Camp2        Desc2     AB          NULL
    4    Camp3        Desc3     AC          NULL
    5    Camp4        Desc4     NULL        AD
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!). ***Please*** stop using it! If you'd be using the **proper ANSI JOIN** syntax, it would be a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of a `INNER JOIN` - that simple ...

Comment: How are the two tables `@PostCodes pc` and `Campaign C ` relates to each others? By which key?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal: Postcodes and Campaign dont relate to each other, its campaign.campaignid = campaignpostcode.campaignid and campaignpostcode.postcodedistrict = Postcodes.postcodes

Hope thats clears your doubt

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
SELECT 
   C.CampaignId, C.Name, C.Description,C.EndedOn, C.Active, C.Manager, 
   P.PostcodeArea, P.PostcodeDistrict
FROM 
   Campaign C
INNER JOIN
   CampaignPostcode P ON P.CampaignId = C.CampaignId
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   @PostCodes pc ON P.PostcodeDistrict = pc.Postcodes 
WHERE 
   C.EndedOn IS NULL
```

Comment: Its not working. FYI, C.EndedOn is a part of query and not intended to return unmatched rows. So please include it as a part of query.

Comment: @DotNetGeek: well your question is very vague about how the tables are related, and in which table you have "unmatched" rows that you want to show - but this query should give you an idea of how to do it! Use the table(s) that have all rows, and then join the table(s) that may or may not have rows using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Comment: I have edited the post to give better clarity on what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT   
  p.*
FROM @PostCodes AS PC
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT *
  FROM Campaign C
  INNER JOIN CampaignPostcode P ON  P.CampaignId = C.CampaignId
) AS p ON P.PostcodeDistrict = pc.Postcodes
WHERE P.EndedOn IS NULL
```

Comment: thanks @Mahmoud, I will try this. FYI, I have edited the post to give better clarity on what I need.

Comment: @DotNetGeek - Can you please explain the logic behind that? Specially the fifth row, I can get the first 4 rows, then you will need to use `UNION` to get the fifth row, but I don't understand the idea behind it. [**Here is the first four rows**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/95196/16)

Comment: I would like to build a result that contains the rows which involved in campaign as well as, not involved, then I would like to bind the result to the grid. Hope that helps. Also, I am already having the result for the included 4 rows.

Comment: @DotNetGeek You can easily get all the 5 compigns, but the problem is the two columns `PostcodeIn`, `PostcodeOut` how they are computed for each compiagn from the three tables, that what I don't understand. I can easily get all the rows but the problem is in the `PostcodeOut`.

Comment: thats just fictional, you can use whatever u feel like, its just my thinking. btw, thanks for your quick response.